# URL redirection in Apache rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I installed a Aava shopping cart **jadasite** on a shared Java webhost and now my home page is like `http://www.mydomain.com/jada/web/fe/localhost/English/home`.

To make my home page appear at `http://www.mydomain.com` I need to make changes in the Apache's mod_rewrite rule. I don't know much about the Apache server.

Can you please tell me what should be the code for Apache's rewrite rule and where do I need to put it.

Comment: Why dont make the DocumentRoot in httpd.conf point direct to that directory?

Comment: i think that also is an option.but i dont know about redirect rule of apache.so dont know the exact code to put there.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure you want this - put into .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jada/web/fe/localhost/English/home/$1 [QSA,L]
```

However i feel there is server misconfiguration at your end. If you have direct access to apache configs you may want to set right vhosts. Here is example from my localhost:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    DocumentRoot X:/xampp/htdocs/mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

127.0.0.2 should be your external IP address that apache is listening to. X:/xampp/htdocs/mydomain.com can be any folder you want (folders outside htdocs dir may need additional directives in order to work).

Comment: thanks .i am using a java shared host.i am not sure about direct access to apache configs .will have to check it with host.

Comment: then this rewrite rule should work. unlike solution offered below rewrite rule would keep your URL nice and tidy without '/jada/web/fe/localhost/English/home' part.

Comment: Hi i tried the rewrite rule you mentioned above but it dosnt seem to work.i put it in the .htaccess file but still am not getting the page redirection.

Comment: oh im sorry, i left small mistake in it. now it is corrected. you can test rewrite rules at http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ if you ever need that.

Comment: Hi mate  i tried the above and tested it .it dosnt seem to work there.this is what i put in .htaccess file  RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jada/web/fe/default/English/home/$1 [QSA,L].i put my .htaccess file in the root directory of my server.

Comment: I wrote to my host and this is what he wrote back .All requests are mapped from apache to tomcat via mod_proxy_ajp

so public_html/.htaccess is not read
.htaccess in tomcat directories is also never read

You may want to add welcome-file-list to your web.xml

Comment: well im not familiar with tomcat so i guess i wont be of much help here :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you could redirect with an htaccess file or you could upload an index.php file to your root and write this line of code

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/jada/web/fe/localhost/English/home');
?>
```

Comment: thanks but i am not using php here.jadasite is a java shopping cart.i am using apache with tomcat container

Comment: every shared host support php as far as i know sir